# Views Contextual Filter Match criteria with contains instead of equal to

Tags: 7, views

When setting up contextual filters, its fixed setting is if the argument **equals** the result. I want to be able to choose if my result **contains** my argument string. How can this be done?

Comment: Please check this essential [Topic](https://othermachines.com/blog/filter-form-submission-data-field-value-views-webform) for views and its path.

Answer (score 3):

Try using [Views Argument Substitutions](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_argument_substitutions)

> Contextual Filters allow a View to be filtered based on arguments
>   passed via URL or other embedded method (e.g. the View Reference
>   module), **but contextual filters are inflexible compared with normal
>   filters (which allow for "contains," "begins with," "ends with,"
>   etc.).**
>
> **This module allows contextual filter arguments to be used as
>   replacement tokens in filters** and table arguments, so that passed-in
>   arguments (such as from URLs or View Reference fields) can be used as
>   values in normal View filters.

[image]

Comment: Was this something you used on a previous project? I was looking for something where I didn't have to install another module with my ever growing module folder. thanks tho.

Comment: @Patoshi it was something I just found, never had such scenario like yours come up yet.

Comment: but yes that module did do the trick for passing in arguments and then linking it back into the **filter criteria** section as a token reference.

Comment: This was magic. Thank you!